# How to rewrite a legacy C++ code in C# that uses AfxGetThreadState, PeekMessage, PumpMessage?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, serial-port, wait

I am writing a small assembly in C# that would achieve the same functionality as a legacy C++ class, CCommsController. That said class instantiates a COM object in its constructor; the COM object implements an interface that allows the CCommscontroller to communicate with a device over a good old fashion serial interface.

The CCommsController has a WaitAndDoEvents method that is the most difficult for me to write it in C#. The WaitAndDoEvents is called after a message was sent to the device and it is awaiting for the hardware to reply.

Below is the piece of the code where the QueueCommand will call the appropriate COM interface to send the strCmd string to the port, followed by the retrieval of reply.

```
//...
if( !QueueCommand( (LPCTSTR)strCmd, nTimeout, CMD_PRIORITY_LOW, nCmdID ) ){
        strReply = "ERROR - Failed to queue command.";
        return( FALSE );
}

wait_object = GetCommandWaitObject( nCmdID );

//...

if( ( wait_object != NULL ) && WaitAndDoEvents( wait_object ) ){
    // Successfull command completion.
    return( GetSendResult( nCmdID, strReply, wait_object ) );
}
```

I need advice on how to think in C# when it comes down to dealing with WinAPI calls.
Here is the outline of the C++  code that I need help with.

```
BOOL CCommsController::WaitAndDoEvents( HANDLE object )
{
    BOOL quit_flag = FALSE;
    WPARAM quit_param;
    DWORD ret;
    int status = 0;
#if _MFC_VER >= 0x0700
    MSG *pMsg = &(AfxGetThreadState()->m_msgCur);
#else
    MSG *pMsg = &(AfxGetThread()->m_msgCur);
#endif
   
    while( !status ){
        ret = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects( 1, &object, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT );
    
        switch( ret ){
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            // We got a Windows message.
            // Process all of the pending Windows messages in this next loop.
            while( ::PeekMessage( pMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE ) ){
                  
                if( !AfxGetThread()->PumpMessage() ){
                    quit_param = pMsg->wParam;
                    quit_flag = TRUE;
                }
            }
            break;
        // … here, other cases also implemented that may change the value of status…//
          
        }
    } 
    // … here, more code that interprets the status …//   
    
    if( quit_flag ){
        // Put WM_QUIT back into the main message loop so the
        // application will get it later and quit.
        ::PostQuitMessage( (int)quit_param );
    }
    if( status ){
        return( FALSE );
    }else{
        return( TRUE );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use (Win32) events in C# too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle (see the example). You can also write Win32 interop code with .NET (bind to PeekMessage etc.) although in general you don't need it, it may be easier if you're uncomfortable with C# or if you don't want to rewrite or rearchitecture too much of your code.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of rewriting this in C#? If what you need is a way to make this code immediately available to other C# code you're probably better off turning it into a [Windows Runtime component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/). This allows you to keep all the native code (except for the MFC-specific code), and it provides all the building blocks to implement asynchronous operations.

Comment: @IInspectable, The goal is to make the functionality of an old C++ application available to C#, VB application. A secondary goal is to learn the techniques in C# to interact with drivers and ports and COM objects that are more "natural" (at least to me) in native code.

Comment: For the primary goal, go with a Windows Runtime component. It can be consumed by any .NET language (C#, VB.NET, F#, probably, too), [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), or any programming language that can interface with C (e.g. C++, Rust, Delphi, Swift, Go, Python, ...). The secondary goal is odd: You won't learn about COM by using C# any more than you'd learn about the art of cooking by eating a meal. More than two decades later it remains a mystery to me, why the CLR folks decided upon an object layout that's incompatible with COM's.

Comment: @IInspectable, Thank you for pointing out C++/WinRT technology. Fascinating what they achieved with this new library. It could be a vehicle for me in the future. The reason for my question was that my work often times involves integrating all sorts of devices into a .net/C#,VB appl. These devices come with some protocol implemented as COM object or dll. My point is that from a C# application, it is always a trouble to deal with them. Last time, I built a /CLI wrapper around a third-party library and it wasn't fun. Now, I am looking at using VS Interop support. But that lead to WinAPI calls.